# Permanent Headers using ={"ColA", "ColB", ColC"} and repeat for all sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Sheet1A1, I have the following as my headers for the entire 1st row:

```
={"filmURL", "title", "year", "runtime", "director", "country", "language"}
```

This is a wonderful trick I learned here. You can clear an entire column by selecting the Col Letter, without affecting the header. I want to use the exact same header rows across all my sheets in this workbook. So in Sheet2A1 and Sheet3A1 etc I want what's in Sheet1A1 (then I only need go to one place to edit).

I went to Sheet2A1 and tried `=Sheet1!A1` but that didn't work.
I tried naming Sheet1A1 and then in Sheet2A1 I tried `="Titles"`, and that didn't work. In both cases I'm only getting the first title in the 'list': `filmURL` and nothing more.
I also tried `=Sheet1!A1:A10` but I got the same results.

I remember yet another trick I learned here, something that amounts to a shortcut to a cell so that you don't always have to repeat the `Sheet!` bit in formulas, but I can't find it, so I haven't tried that yet. I can't use importrange or any of that because everyhing is in the one cell.

Am I snookered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

In this case, it supposes that `={"filmURL", "title", "year", "runtime", "director", "country", "language"}` is put in the cell "A1" of "Sheet1".

#### Sample formula 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:G1)
```

- This sample retrieves the values of the cells "A1:G1" of "Sheet1".

#### Sample formula 2:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A1),"[\=\{\}"" ]",""),",")
```

- This sample retrieves the formula of cell "A1" of "Sheet1" and each value is retrieved from the formula.

Comment: both work perfectly!  Thank you. I'll use the first because it is simpler.